# About the usage of files with a .BUILD suffix in Bazel

Tags: build, bazel

Recently, I'm studying Bazel following the tutorial in http://www.bazel.io/docs/tutorial. I have known the usage of BUILD files, but I'm still confused about the usage of files having a .BUILD suffix, e.g. when they are involved in the building process, what their syntax is and what the differences are between them and BUILD files (though they look similar). Since I cannot find any documents introducing ".BUILD" files either on above link or by googling, could anyone explain the usage of ".BUILD" files to me, or provide me some references? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where did you see a file with a .BUILD suffix? Bazel looks for "BUILD" files and doesn't do anything with "something.BUILD".

Answer (score 0):

The documentation about Bazel concepts is at http://www.bazel.io/docs/build-ref.html and the part on BUILD files is at  http://www.bazel.io/docs/build-ref.html#BUILD_files